# Custom binaries on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, buildpack, lpsolve

I'm trying to get the [lp_solve](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/) library working on Heroku, but can't seem to get it to be recognized. I've tried every resource I've been able to find, including working with [vulcan](https://github.com/heroku/vulcan), adding it to the `/bin` directory of my project, adding it in `/vendor` and altering the PATH, and I've even gone so far as to create a [buildpack](https://github.com/mockdeep/heroku-buildpack-lpsolve) which I'm using with [buildpack-multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi), but in each case the results are the same: `No such file or directory`. Even when I bash into my instance and try executing the file directly it gives me the same error. I've made it executable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the nondescript error message, it turns out that it was an architecture issue. It was a 32 bit binary, which I thought might work fine despite that since I had no problems running on it my local machine. I had to recompile it from source on Heroku using Anvil: https://github.com/ddollar/anvil

The guys on the Heroku mailing list were super helpful in debugging the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just include the binary, assuming that it's been compiled against the correct architecture.  When you fire up the heroku console how are you trying to execute the file (what's the full command that you're running)?  Are you having it look for a file that is not there?

Comment: The file was there. I ran `heroku run bash` and tab completed `bin/lp_solve`. Same error no matter what. Based on some advice from the guys on the Heroku emailing list I ran `ldd` and `file` and discovered that it just wasn't finding the headers it wanted.